# Creating pairs of non-intersecting set from a given set

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, algorithm, sets, subset

Let's say I have a set {a,b,c,d} and I want to create a list of pairs {{a,b,c,d},{}},{{a,b,c},{d}},{{a,b,c},{}},... such that there is no intersection between each pair, and they do not need to use all the elements. The ordering does not matter.
Below is my first attempt

```
Clear[a, b, c, d]
allsubsets = Subsets[{a, b, c, d}]
comp = Reverse[allsubsets](*get the complement*)
paired = Table[
{allsubsets[[i]], #} & /@ comp
, {i, 1, Length[allsubsets]}];
result = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[paired, 1]]
Length[result]
```

However, there is still many repeating elements due to the ordering. And I generated a lot of redundant sets so the program is terribly inefficient. This will run (with 4 elements, but I hope it can be extended to more general case) about 10,000 times in the whole program, so the speed may be of interest. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Your `result` can be obtained using [`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html):

```
Tuples[allsubsets, 2] == Sort @ result
```

> True

You can construct non-intersecting pairs directly from `allsubsets`:

```
pairs = Join @@ Table[{i, #} & /@ Subsets[Complement[{a, b, c, d}, i]], {i, allsubsets}];

Length @ pairs
```

> 81

Alternatively, you can use

```
pairs2 = Select[Tuples[allsubsets, 2], DisjointQ @@ #&]

pairs2 == pairs
```

> True

Comment: This does not agree with my understanding of OP's explanation, "such that there is no intersection between each pair".

Comment: @C.E, thank you; just added the missing piece.